# Voronoi Solver - What does this edge construction method do?

Tags: algorithm, voronoi

I have stumbled across an implementation of Fortunes algorithm for a Voronoi diagram solver which works but I am unsure what is actually happening in the `__construct` method of the `Edge` class posted below (some snippets removed for clarity).

```
class Edge
{
    //removed member vars

    function __construct($start, $left_site_event, $right_site_event)
    {
        //removed property assignment
        //this->start = $start //etc etc

        $this->f = ($right_site_event->position->x - $left_site_event->position->x) / ($left_site_event->position->y - $right_site_event->position->y);
        $this->g = $start->y - $this->f * $start->x;

        $this->direction = new Vector(($right_site_event->position->y - $left_site_event->position->y), ($right_site_event->position->x - $left_site_event->position->x));
    }
};
```

The three lines i'm interested in comprehending are the assignment of the `f`, `g` and `direction` based on the position of both the left and right site events.

For a start, the `f` and `g` variables seem poorly named unless these adhere to some kind of formulaic nomenclature? What do these appertain to and what is actually calculated/determined here?

The direction would seem to me that it indicates the slope of the edge between both the left and right site events. Again, what is calculated here?

Any help in understanding this would be appreciated as it appears that the implementation I have found seems to flake out when two site events lie on the same y axis (i.e.: both the left and right site event y coordinates are the same).

**Update**

I have added a screenshot of the current results from my implementation ported from the source I found (see below). Also, if it is of any help to anyone, you can grab the latest (not quite working) copy of the solver from [github](https://github.com/CaptainRedmuff/Voronoi).

[image: Voronoi Solver]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a lot like `f` & `g` are meant to be calculating the [slope & intercept of a straight line through the points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_line#Cartesian_plane), but the author mucked it up. If you'll allow me to abuse notation, `f` is defined as a ratio of an x coordinate value to a y coordinate value, which I'll write as `f ~ x/y`. Which means that in the definition of `g`, you're subtracting a `f*x ~ x^2 / y` term from a `y` term.

Now if `f` were actually meant to be defined as `f ~ y/x`, then in `g`'s definition you'd be subtracting a `f*x ~ y` term from a `y` term, which would make much more sense. I also think the author might have accidentally lost a -1 in the definition of `f` (which is why the denominator is the opposite way round from the numerator), but I can't say for sure without seeing the rest of the code.

Also when the y-coordinates of the left and right site are the same, you get a division by zero in the definition of `f` which is probably why it's mucking up.

If you could explain what the `start` point represents, and whether the algorithm is sweeping from the left or the right, I might be able to figure out exactly what it's trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately most of the mathematic equations used in the source code I found are beyond me. I do however believe that the algorithm scans from bottom to top, left to right. If it's any help, you can view my ported implementation into Objective C for the edge https://github.com/CaptainRedmuff/Voronoi/blob/master/Voronoi/Voronoi/VoronoiEdge.m and the solving implementation https://github.com/CaptainRedmuff/Voronoi/blob/master/Voronoi/Voronoi/VoronoiSolver.m#L171

Comment: Yeah, lines 474 & 475 of VoronoiSolver.m show that `f` is indeed supposed to be the slope of the edge, and `g` the y-intercept of the line containing the edge. I'm pretty confident now that line 42 of VoronoiEdge.m is mistaken - the numerator and denominator should be the other way round. More, I think `start` is the point where the edge is "born", and the left site and right site events are where the edge intersects the parabola that it originated from. e: There's also something funky going on with the x and y coordinates being interchanged, but I can't decipher which way round was intended.

Comment: I have tried switching the numerator and denominator around but it doesn't appear to yield any better results. From the image I added to my question, it almost looks like the its the edge finishing that is incorrect but strangely, only for certain events.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't spare the time to go through the codebase and debug it. You might want to consider adapting another implementation though, because frankly that one looks much more convoluted than it should be. [The version linked off the bottom of this post](http://blog.ivank.net/fortunes-algorithm-and-implementation.html) is heavily commented and seems pretty clear. There's also [this one](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~mbrubeck/voronoi.html) if you prefer brevity. Good luck!

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your help. You have answered my original question which was all I really wanted to know. Thank you for the links to alternative implementations. I will have a look at these and see if I can rewrite the solver to yield better results.